# traverse a model from one orientdb instance and duplicate result into another orientDb instance

Tags: orientdb

I am having an orientDB instance where all my vertex and relations are stored. I am trying to search node via a searchable property, get node and traverse complete tree associated. I get the result chunk ( made up of all Vertex and Edges connected to my search node).

Now I would like to push result ( all vertex with edge) to another OrientDB instance. 
Please suggest what will be best way to do it and how.

I am able to use tinkerpop graph APIs to get traversal result, but not sure how can I push this dataset to another orientdb. I want to maintain connected-ness  in second instance too.

Comment: It's not clear if you want to create your own replication strategy (why don't use the default one?) or if you want to replicate sub-graphs disconnected from the main.

Comment: Yes , want to create sub graphs from main. Please assist.

Comment: @Lvca , Sir can you please suggest ?